# Firebase Re-authentication error: Contextual closure type '(AuthDataResult?, Error?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

So, I tried to add a delete account function using Firebase Manage User service [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user), it's showing me error. Below is the code.

```
@IBAction func deleteAccount() {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        var credential: AuthCredential
                
        user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
            if let error = error {
                self.redAlert(message: "Unable to authenticate. Please try again.")
            } else {
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete { error in
                  if let error = error {
                      self.redAlert(message: "An error happened. Please contact support to delete your account")
                  } else {
                      self.greenAlert(message: "Your account has been deleted")
                  }
              }
            }
        }
```

Attached the screenshot as well.

It keeps showing "Contextual closure type '(AuthDataResult?, Error?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body" which I really don't know how to fix it. Would you mind helping to pinpoint this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeUuD.png)

---

EDIT: I actually found the solution. The right code should be:

```
@IBAction func deleteAccount(_send: Any) {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let emailText: String = email.text!
    let passwordText: String = password.text!
    var credential: AuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: emailText, password: passwordText)
    
    user?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.redAlert(message: "Unable to authenticate. Please try again.")
        } else {
            Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete { error in
              if let error = error {
                  self.redAlert(message: "An error happened. Please contact support to delete your account")
              } else {
                  self.greenAlert(message: "Your account has been deleted")
                  self.stopLoading()
                  self.logout()
              }
          }
        }
    })
    
}
```

Hope it helps anyone that is struggling!